# Why does Nvenc Encoder improve decoding speed?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to improve the speed of decoding h264 video to mp4 video using Ffmpeg in c++. I have found a cli command that can do that but I still do not fully understand the command to reproduce it in c++ so I hope you guys can give me an explanation.

The command that I found uses h264_nvenc encoder to improve the speed using GPU. However, I cannot understand why an h264 encoder would improve the speed of decoding h264 video (or maybe encoding to mp4 frame). Can anyone please give me a detailed explanation?

Here is the cli command that I found:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -r 120 -i <input_file> -c:v h264_nvenc -preset fast -b:v 8M -vf scale=960:1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p <output_file> -y
```

Thanks

Edited: 
Log of command with option "-c:v h264_nvenc"

```
C:\Users\Shared\GolfTec\test>ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -r 120 -i C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\raw0.h264 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset medium -b:v 8M -vf scale=960:1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\video0.mp4 -y
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray 
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy 
--enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 
--enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis 
--enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc 
--enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0000027ecb2a6700] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, h264, from 'C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\raw0.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (CAVLC 4:4:4), yuv444p(progressive), 960x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\video0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x1080, q=-1--1, 8000 kb/s, 120 fps, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/8000000 buffer size: 16000000 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  269 fps=261 q=25.0 Lsize=    2551kB time=00:00:02.23 bitrate=9356.5kbits/s speed=2.17x
video:2549kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.074325%
```

Log of command without option "-c:v h264_nvenc"

```
C:\Users\Shared\GolfTec\test>ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -r 120 -i C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\raw0.h264 -preset medium -b:v 8M -vf scale=960:1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\video0.mp4 -y
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libmfx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0000021e33556640] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, h264, from 'C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\raw0.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (CAVLC 4:4:4), yuv444p(progressive), 960x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] profile High, level 4.2
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=8000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\\Users\\Shared\\GolfTec\\test\\video0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x1080, q=-1--1, 8000 kb/s, 120 fps, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/8000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  269 fps= 39 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2279kB time=00:00:02.21 bitrate=8423.8kbits/s speed=0.32x
video:2277kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.119200%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] frame I:2     Avg QP:25.09  size: 16508
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] frame P:193   Avg QP:23.94  size:  9094
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] frame B:74    Avg QP:23.92  size:  7332
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] consecutive B-frames: 62.8%  1.5%  0.0% 35.7%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] mb I  I16..4: 38.2% 54.3%  7.6%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] mb P  I16..4:  9.2% 11.8%  0.8%  P16..4: 46.5%  3.4%  3.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.5%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] mb B  I16..4:  4.3%  3.7%  0.2%  B16..8: 35.0%  1.5%  0.2%  direct: 9.5%  skip:45.5%  L0:56.6% L1:40.9% BI: 2.5%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] final ratefactor: 19.31
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] 8x8 transform intra:53.1% inter:88.1%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 22.0% 41.2% 4.5% inter: 12.8% 39.4% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 32% 19% 31%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 14% 17% 54%  2%  3%  3%  4%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 11%  9% 63%  3%  4%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 63% 23% 13%  1%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:86.0% UV:64.8%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] ref P L0: 53.6%  8.3% 17.1% 11.4%  9.6%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] ref B L0: 58.9% 14.4% 26.6%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] ref B L1: 84.8% 15.2%
[libx264 @ 0000021e335589a0] kb/s:8317.64
```

Comment: It's just using special NVidia features for GPU acceleration of an otherwise normal h264 encoding/decoding job. What do you mean reproduce it in c++ though?

Comment: @Benny Mackney I understand it is using special NVidia feature. But is is using a h264 encoder which is used for speeding up the encoding of h264. So, why does it improve the speed for decoding h264 or encoding it to mp4 format?

Comment: I am trying to understand how this work so that I can do this in c++ using ffmpeg library

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg And it speeds up both because both the encoder and the decoder are called "nvenc"

Comment: Not exactly. The encoder is either "nvdec" or "cuvid" and not "nvenc". Also, the decoder does not work on my hardware for some reasons. That's why I am looking into the encoder.

Comment: Share full log of your command.

Comment: @Gyan I have updated the question with logs of commands with and without using the h264_nvenc encoder codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Decoding is a much faster process and so normally is rate-limited by further processing, mainly the encoder but also by filters. See the full speed of the s/w h264 decoder by running

```
ffmpeg -r 120 -i <input_file> -an -f null -
```

Add filtering to estimate the slow down due to filters.

```
ffmpeg -r 120 -i <input_file> -vf scale=960:1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -f null -
```

This happens because ffmpeg carries out transcoding in a sequential fashion:

demux -> decode -> filter -> encode -> mux -> back to step 1 ...

Comment: That's seem reasonable and I will test it tmr. Thanks